# How to calculate time difference between two dates

Tags: php, date

How to Calculate time difference between two dates in php?

```
$date1=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date2=date('2015-03-06 45:06:03');(Db)
```

am trying to do once time difference between 2 hours send Mail to user.Current datetime and Db datetime difference between 2 hours mean Send Mail to user.How to Check?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try  $diff=$date1 - $dates?

Answer (score 0):

strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp and divide by 3600 to find result in hours. Try like this..

```
$date1=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date2=date('2015-03-06 45:06:03');
echo $diff_hours = (strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2))/3600;
```